# Uber API calls with scrapy

Tags: python, api, curl, web-scraping, scrapy

Here is a `curl` command which is working perfect:

```
curl -X POST -k -H 'X-Csrf-Token: '\'\' -i 'https://www.uber.com/api/loadSearchJobsResults?localeCode=fr-FR'
```

While in scrapy shell, the Request is redirecting and showing 404 status code:

**scrapy code**

```
>>> fetch(scrapy.Request(url,method='POST',headers = {'x-Csrf-Token':''}))
2020-11-05 12:26:49 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <POST https://www.uber.com/api/loadSearchJobsResults?localeCode=fr-FR> (referer: None)
>>> fetch(scrapy.Request(url,method='POST',headers = {'x-Csrf-Token':'x'}))
2020-11-05 12:26:57 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <POST https://www.uber.com/pk/ur/api/loadSearchJobsResults/?localeCode=fr-FR> from <POST https://www.uber.com/api/loadSearchJobsResults?localeCode=fr-FR>
2020-11-05 12:26:58 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <POST https://www.uber.com/pk/ur/api/loadSearchJobsResults/?localeCode=fr-FR> (referer: None)
```

Where am I missing?

Comment: There could be many things, such as headers (e.g. user-agent), the case of the token header, its value (`cURL` sends the 2-character string `''`, your Scrapy code sends an empty string)…

Comment: @Gallaecio, Thanks for commenting. Would you please add something to an answer as I have already tried various similar ways.

Answer (score 0):

[@Gallaecio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939364/gallaecio) gave the clue:

> the case of the token header, its value (cURL sends the 2-character
> string '', your Scrapy code sends an empty string)

Whenever you must convert curl requests to scrapy, I suggest to you use the following utilities: Postman (CTRL + O -> Raw Text), `scrapy.utils.curl.curl_to_request_kwargs('write curl request')` or [Michael's website curl2scrapy](https://michael-shub.github.io/curl2scrapy/)

I've used Postman, so in scrapy's shell you should fetch like this:

```
fetch('https://www.uber.com/api/loadSearchJobsResults?localeCode=fr-FR', headers={'X-Csrf-Token': "''"}, method='POST')
```